# asp .net core passing a list from html

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I have a `div` that works for creating items but when I am editing items that are already there for a shipment. I have a `frombody` on the C# side that converts the response to a list but the products that already exist do not get added to the list.

```
@foreach (var product in Model.ShipmentForm.ShipmentProducts)
{
    <div class="shipment-product">

        @Html.HiddenFor(model=>product.Id)
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
            <!-- Product details -->
            @{
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => product.Product.Id, new SelectList(Model.GetProducts(), "Id", "Name"), "Select a Product", new { @class = "form-control" })
            }
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => product.Quantity, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => product.Quantity)
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => product.CustomsAMount, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => product.CustomsAMount)
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => product.FreightAmount, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => product.FreightAmount)
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-product">Remove</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

then in JS

```
var productIndex = @Model.ShipmentForm.ShipmentProducts.Count;

$("#add-product").click(function () {
    var productHtml = `
    <div class="shipment-product">
             <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">

            <select name="ShipmentForm.ShipmentProducts[${productIndex}].Product.Id" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Select a Product</option>
                @foreach (var product in Model.GetProducts())
                {
                                        <option value="@product.Id">@product.Name</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">

        <input type="text" name="ShipmentForm.ShipmentProducts[${productIndex}].CustomsAMount" class="form-control" />

               </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" name="ShipmentForm.ShipmentProducts[${productIndex}].FreightAmount" class="form-control" />

                </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" name="ShipmentForm.ShipmentProducts[${productIndex}].Quantity" class="form-control" />

                </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-product">Remove</button>
                </div>
                        </div>
    </div>
`;

    $("#shipment-products").append(productHtml);
    productIndex++;
});
```

How do I get the @html tag to generate the index like the JS does?